# Retrofit return null response for calling Get Api from android ,In Postman its working fine

Tags: rest, gson, retrofit, retrofit2, get-request

I am using retrofit to make a call. But in the response of the API its returns null , check below

```
 <-- 200 OK http://staging.api.server.com:4200/api/User/my-leadership?filter=%7B%7D (208ms)
 Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
 Date: Tue, 09 Mar 2021 07:59:57 GMT
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: 4
 Connection: keep-alive
 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
 X-Frame-Options: DENY
 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains
 X-Download-Options: noopen
 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 ETag: W/"4-K+iMpCQsduglOsYkdIUQZQMtaDM"
 Vary: Accept-Encoding
 null
 <-- END HTTP (4-byte body)
```

calling API method

```
 @GET(ServerURL.GET_CHAT_DATA)
    Call<ChatData> getChatData(@Query("filter") String filter);
```

Call API from retrofit

```
  @Override
    public void getChatData(Context context, final IOnLeadershipExpInteractedListener expInteractedListener) {
 if (Utils.isConnectedToInternet(context)) {

            Call<ChatData> leadershipCall = ServerApiClient.getRetroInstance().getChatData("{}");
            leadershipCall.enqueue(new Callback<ChatData>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ChatData> call, Response<ChatData> response) {
                    expInteractedListener.hideLoadingDialog();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        //expInteractedListener.onSuccessChatData(null);//"response.body()");
                    } else {
                        expInteractedListener.onError(response);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ChatData> call, Throwable t) {
                    expInteractedListener.hideLoadingDialog();
                    expInteractedListener.onRetroRequestFailure();
                }
            });

        } else {
            expInteractedListener.showNoInternetDialog();
        }
}
```

Model class is

```
public class ChatData {
    Result result;
}
```

I am using this model class here because I am getting dynamic data in success response so I am parsing that data manually into code.

Success response getting from postman call it's like

```
{
  "Ledata": {
    "item1": 0,
    "item2": 7,
    "item3": 0,
    "item4": 6.6875,
    "item5": 0,
    "item6": 0.0057,
    "item7": 5.2708,
    "item8": 1.0208
  },
  "devle": {
    "3bf0d675-370b-4149-b0b3-059b63b8ecf0": {
      "item6": 0.0057
    }
  },
  "roleexpcat": {
    "2beacf3b-5203-4f49-8a28-e5e987265c47": {
      "item1": 0.5
    },
    "2d70bf26-058b-44b2-a63d-f14dc0b38c6d": {
      "item1": 3
    },
    "3bf0d675-370b-4149-b0b3-059b63b8ecf0": {
      "item1": 1.0208,
      "item2": 1.0208
    },
    "3c20a6c3-0ead-45b1-8630-53a7bb78f7c7": {
      "item4": 2.375
    },
    "47bd8c99-0602-4515-a6a8-77bef882521b": {
      "item4": 0.4167
    },
    "4bd994f7-996a-4d31-88d1-e983d11e998e": {
      "item5": 3
    },
    "4d1170d1-17c7-48ef-b3d7-240589d34319": {
      "item5": 0.5
    },
    "4f863bbb-d682-4e73-a188-7f0dcc44a690": {
      "item6": 0.2292,
      "item4": 0.4583
    },
    "7c1aaa86-b8ef-4b72-ab09-8312425c96b3": {
      "item6": 3
    },
    "7e8fab5f-dd8c-4490-9b42-8ad719bb0b5d": {
      
    },
    "be4cb60c-c9de-40db-902c-a42a93d4d57e": {
      "item6": 3
    },
    "e9db0527-2940-44af-8b97-327fee3c64cd": {
      "item8": 0.4583
    },
    "f87b1c77-6d88-4d12-a0ab-91ef5d279597": {
      "item4": 1
    },
    "fb3c3c5c-ddb2-429b-9d98-44f8397e8598": {
      
    }
  },
  "sharedon": null,
  "originallep": null,
  "internalname": "8c05c0bc-27b9-4866-af44-b43847e18175",
  "name": "8c05c0bc-27b9-4866-af44-b43847e1817t",
  "status": "Enabled",
  "createdat": "2021-02-23T20:43:35.288Z",
  "shared": false,
  "sortorder": null,
  "transactionid": null,
  "ownership_details": "8c05c0bc-27b9-4866-af44-b43847e18176",
  "companyid": "69585844-497b-4355-b5a8-0eef5088f545",
  "id": "6541c2d2-8938-4cb4-bef8-387878646566"
}
```

Please help me to resolve the null response error in this retrofit API call. As I am not getting any type of error in my android studio logcat. That makes it hard to understand why this happens here.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is just that it returns null, but it looks like the model `ChatData` is also not correctly built for the json you've posted.

Comment: @Fred I am using this model class to parse dynamic data manually in code. If you have any suggestions, most welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by manual. The thing is that you made it a return type from retrofit and unless you have a custom deserializer, it won't deserialize your json.